# Split column values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have one table with two columns id and data. The values in the table are as follows:

```
id|data|
1 |A,B |
2 |B,C |
3 |C,D |
4 |D,A |
5 |E,C |
```

I need number of A,B,C,D,E present in the table as follows. Please note:  columns are dynamic means they are dependent upon the values in the data column from the table:

```
A|B|C|D|E|
2|2|3|2|1|
```

And I have written the following query:

```
SELECT id,s.data 
FROM  my_table t, 
      unnest(string_to_array(t.data, ',')) s(data);
```

The output is given as follows:

```
id|data|
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
1 | A  |
```

Comment: I suppose I don't need to mention that you should probably re-engineer your schema so that this "SQL gymnastics" is not necessary :-) If you *ever* find yourself trying to process sub-columns (parts of a column), you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: stop wasting time on this and fix your data

Comment: is 2 values in data columns fixed?

Comment: yes@BhaveshGhodasara

Comment: Modify that query to group by s.data and change `id` to `count(*)`

Comment: yes it is working@roby

Comment: There is no way to get dynamic columns, net even with proper normalization, and not even with crosstab (that require to mention output columns either). But why do you want SQL columns in the first place? You can have your data in a `value, count` format easily (f.ex. `'A', 2` is a row in that format) and display those data to/in your client/UI as you like.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the query which provide exact output which you want.

```
select * from crosstab ('SELECT ''Total'':: text, s.data, count(*)::int 
FROM my_table t, unnest(string_to_array(t.data, '','')) s(data) 
group by s.data') as ct(Total text, A int, B int, C int, D int, E int)
```

Please create extension tablefunc (if not created).